# Convert Arabic TTF/OTF fonts to woff, eof?

Tags: css, fonts, truetype, webfonts, opentype

First I know there are similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979826/how-can-i-convert-otf-ttf-files-to-eot-format) to mine,

and I do tried [Font Squirrel Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) for tons of **Arabic** fonts, all of them render text in English correctly but none of them worked with Arabic letters!!

so is there a desktop tool (since all web apps is not working) than can convert Arabic fonts without breaking them ??

I have purchased an Arabic font, and I just want to convert it so I can use it on the web, and I did not like the idea to pay subscriptions to some fancy websites like [fonts.com](http://webfonts.fonts.com/) each month to provide me with these fonts !

and in case you're wondering about my CSS here you go:

```
/* CSS */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GESSTVBold';
    src: url('arabic-3/ge_ss_tv_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('arabic-3/ge_ss_tv_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('arabic-3/ge_ss_tv_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('arabic-3/ge_ss_tv_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('arabic-3/ge_ss_tv_bold-webfont.svg#GESSTVBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

} 

.ar {
    font-family:"GESSTVBold";  
}

<!-- HTML -->
<h1 class="ar">مرحبا بالخط العربي</h1>
```

Thanks

Comment: I know you have tried Font Squirrel Generator but it has subsetting option. Maybe it's cutting of your Arabic letters. Have you tried to disable uncheck it in expert mode?

Comment: can you tell me exactly what option should I uncheck it, also if you can write it as an answer so if it works, I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Hope it's not too late, try [font2web](http://www.font2web.com) .. worked for me perfectly, just save your html file with codepage-1256 encoding.

Answer (score 5):

1. Switch the **Font Squirell** to **Expert mode**.
2. Then on **Subsetting:** choose either `No subsetting` or `Custom subsetting`
3. Sorted! :)

**EDIT:**

On custom subsetting you either need to tick your desired subset or type it in the input fields.

Comment: This is close, but it leaves a small spacing problem with some fonts.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use the [font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) but there is no Arabic unicode support, and I tried to set the Unicode ranges: 0600-06FF,0FB50-0FDFF,0FE70- 0FEFE but the same problem in cutting arabic letters is still existed.
finally I tried the site http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-woff and the result was great

[image]

Comment: can you please share the html/css and fonts of that page cause I tried with that website and still the space bug.. I use chrome as browser.

Comment: Please Note that I finally use this site: http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-woff and I succeeded to convert the font from otf to woff, so please attach your otf file and I'll try for you and make a css and sample html, anyway may be some old browser still not support the woff font or maybe your font is not standard

Comment: everythingfonts is limited to 0.4 megabytes, and pushes for upgrading or paying in an aggressive way; so look at your file size (or your budget) before you waste your time there; I just tried with Fira-Sans and it got blocked for size

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any Arabic font on hand so you'll have to try it:

1. upload your font
2. choose expert
3. on the list of options you have subsetting - this cuts off unwanted characters to save bandwidth - try "no subsetting" (unless you know unicode ranges, and you want to specify them)
4. let me know if it worked.

Comment: now I can see Arabic letters but they are still not connected to each other (all letters are separated)

Comment: I'm having the same problem as well, I'm seeing all the letters separated. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with Arabic fonts but just one long shot: some of the unicode features are removed by font squirrel generator. Maybe the contextual ligatures or contextual swashes? You could try subsetting them in different software.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered some issues while converting **Persian** or **Arabic** Fonts. For instance, words became separated. So *الیاس* converted to *ال‌ی‌ا‌س*.

In order to compress Persian font appropriately, I have used [transfonter](https://transfonter.org/) website, and my configurations were as follows:

- `Family support` **checked**
- `local rule` **unchecked**
- `Fix vertical metrics` **unchecked**
- `Base64 encode` **unchecked**
- `Formats:` **WOFF** and **WOFF2**
- `Hinting:` **Strip Hinting**
- `Subset:` **Arabic**
- `Unicode Ranges:` **U+0600-06FF**
- `Font display:` **swap**

The mentioned website could successfully convert `1.1 MB TTF` to `166.1 KB WOFF2`.